# Is there a Rack middleware for using sessions without cookies?

Tags: ruby, session, cookies, rack

The provided session management middleware that comes with Rack are all based on cookies for identifying the user. Since I'm developing an api, I would rather pass the session-id explicitly as a query string parameter. Looking at the code base, it doesn't seem that this use case was taken into consideration, as all the session middlewares extend from a common class, that reads/writes to cookies.

So my question is - Is there a project that maintains an alternative Rack middleware or a monkey patch for racks built-in middleware's, that will allow me to maintain the session-id over the query string, rather than a cookie store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rack can use custom session ID items instead of cookies:

```
require 'rack/session/abstract/id'
```

The Rack documentation may be a helpful place to start your search. I believe you're looking for the "skip" option (or "defer" option).

Docs:

ID sets up a basic framework for implementing an id based sessioning
service. Cookies sent to the client for maintaining sessions will only
contain an id reference. Only #get_session and #set_session are
required to be overwritten.

All parameters are optional.

- :key determines the name of the cookie, by default it is
  'rack.session'
- :path, :domain, :expire_after, :secure, and :httponly set the related
  cookie options as by Rack::Response#add_cookie
- :skip will not a set a cookie in the response nor update the session state
- :defer will not set a cookie in the response but still update the session
  state if it is used with a backend
- :renew (implementation dependent) will prompt the generation of a new
  session id, and migration of data to be referenced at the new id. If
  :defer is set, it will be overridden and the cookie will be set.
- :sidbits sets the number of bits in length that a generated session
  id will be.

These options can be set on a per request basis, at the location of
env['rack.session.options']. Additionally the id of the session can be
found within the options hash at the key :id. It is highly not
recommended to change its value.

Is Rack::Utils::Context compatible.

Not included by default; you must require 'rack/session/abstract/id' to use.

Source:

```
  class ID
    DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
      :key =>           'rack.session',
      :path =>          '/',
      :domain =>        nil,
      :expire_after =>  nil,
      :secure =>        false,
      :httponly =>      true,
      :defer =>         false,
      :renew =>         false,
      :sidbits =>       128,
      :cookie_only =>   true,
      :secure_random => (::SecureRandom rescue false)
    }
```

I hope this gives you a lead... when you learn more, can you share your results here?

### Edit:

The magic trick is to combine options `:cookie_only => false` with `:defer => true`. Of course, the standard Rack::Session::Cookie doesn't make much sense here, so you could do:

```
use Rack::Session::Pool, :cookie_only => false, :defer => true
```

Interestingly you can alter the options in run time. In my use case, I actually need to support a traditional cookie-based mechanism alongside the explicit parameter-passing style, so I have done the following:

```
class WebApp < Sinatra::Base

  configure do
    use Rack::Session::Pool, :key => 'session_id'
  end

  before do
    # Switch to parameter based session management if the client is an ios device
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /iOS/
      session.options[:cookie_only] = false
      session.options[:defer] = true
    end
  end

  get '/' do
    session[:user_id] ||= nil # This triggers a session-write, giving us a valid session-id
    body "session_id=#{session.id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - That looks like a good lead. From skimming the code, I believe I need to set the `:defer` and not the `:skip` param. I'll post back when I have done some experimentation.

Comment: In this example, where is session[:user_id] set to an actual value other than nil? Then, how does the client pass the session_id back to the server to get back the value that session[:user_id] was set to during a previous request?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to eliminate usage of cookies in your API application, but still want to manage sessions. For instance, in my case session identifier came from token.
You need to redefine method `extract_session_id` to extract you session identifier from received token. This method have to be redefined on your session store class, because `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID` provides default implementation, based on cookies.
It is called from `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID#current_session_id` method which calls `#id` method on session object, usually represented by `Rack::Session::Abstract::SessionHash` instance. And inside this `SessionHash#id` method `#extract_session_id` from your session store finally called.

I suppose it would be simpler to have session identifier extractor configured independently, but desire to store session identifiers in cookies along with session data lead to that tricked design.

As well it is a bit weird to see cookie interaction in `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID` class in method `#commit_session` and `#set_cookie`.
So to be completely sure that no cookie will be set you could redefine `#set_cookie` method on your store as well. The same goal probably can be achived by setting `cookie_only: false, defer: true` for your session storage middleware, as mentioned in one of the answer here, but I have not checked this.

Definitely you need to modify your middleware stack to exclude all middlewares which interact with cookies and likely browser specific. On default middleware stack of rails it can be look like this:

```
# config/application.rb
[
  Rack::MethodOverride, # browser specific
  ActionDispatch::Cookies,
  ActionDispatch::Flash
].each do |middleware|
  config.middleware.delete(middleware)
end
```

As well you definitely need to replace session store to something which store information on server side, like redis, for example:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
Rails.application.config.session_store ::Custom::Session::TokenRedisStore
```

In my case, `::Custom::Session::TokenRedisStore` inherits `::RedisSessionStore` and redefined all methods mentioned above.
`::RedisSessionStore` contained in `redis-session-store` gem. So, obviously you need to add it to you `Gemfile` if you going to use it.

I do that for Rails 4.2.x, but same approach can be adopbed to any framework as `Rack` everywhere the same.

Comment: Would `ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore`  work? Isn't it the whole point of sessions (instead of auth tokens): to use store different from database?

Comment: @Vanuan, I don't like the idea of mixing cache with sessions. In implementation they could be very similar, but at some point caching could push out your sessions and this will be a terrible side effect of such approach.

Comment: @Vanuan, In my understanding session and auhtentication token two different things. Sesion represents some state which belongs to particular user, authentication token is a unique sequence which provide you access to that state. Using encryption/signature you can combine things the way that authentication token/cookie will be at the same time of session storage. Almost always on each request you have to restore session and get some information from it. So, it make sense to make it as fast as you can and using in memory key/value storages is only one way of approach this.

Comment: Nothing prevent you from using database, it will be just inefficient in terms of speed and system thoughput.

Comment: I meant that if you use session-id as your "token", you wouldn't be able to list all tokens used if it is stored in memory, while you can if it is stored in a database. I.e. storing in memory is more secure.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the difference in your message between database and memory. You have in memory databases, you can disable transaction sinchronization to disk in postgres and it will be in memory as well :) You can use memcache or redis or whatever to store tokens in memory. It's up to you how you authrorize your users to list tokens and it does not depends on the tokens' storage at all.